# what are the fastest/Popular search technologies

Tags: database, search, indexing, full-text-search

What are the fastest search technologies apart from Relational DB Searches ?

I have a collection of Text Files from varied sources (Banks/Ledgers/Stock Markets). Each line in these Text Files is a Record. Each line can further be parsed into some DB Columns(Stock Name/Date of purchase/Owner/...). It is not necessary that each line has all the fields. If some text is not mathcing any of the fields, I store it as it is in a seperate column(columnA). If the parser fails to find any column at all I just store the Line in columnA.

I than do a DB search based on user Inputs. I find that the search becomes slow after a few million records. I want to move to an alternative storage like File System or some other Indexed storage.

What do you think would be the fastest storage technology for this kind of requirement ?

I am currently using SQLite DB. Since I am about to rewrite the entire code, I will be more than happy if any other storage technology can give me faster results.

Comment: did you try to create indices for your tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) is a
   high-performance, full-featured text
   search engine library written
   entirely in Java. It is a technology
   suitable for nearly any application
   that requires full-text search,
   especially cross-platform.
2. [Lucene.Ne](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)t is a source code,
   class-per-class, API-per-API and
   algorithmatic port of the Java
   Lucene search engine to the C# and
   .NET platform utilizing  Microsoft
   .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Relational databases aren't great at text searching.  Perhaps you could try something more suited to the task like [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).  That said, it seems like you're putting a lot of data in SQLite (it might be a bit "lite" for your purpose).  If you switched to something like MySQL or Postgres you might get the speed you need without much of a rewrite.